# Adding two numbers [1, 10^10000] as arrays of chars - C

Tags: c, arrays, char, numbers, sum

I tackled the problem by first figuring out the length of two given numbers and aligning the one with less digits (if one exists) into a new array so that the ones, tens, hundreds etc. align with the bigger number's ones, tens, hundreds, etc. 
Then I wanted to save the sum of each two aligned elements (with a mod of 10) into a new array while checking if the sum of digits is greater than 10 - just the basic sum stuff. Now the problem occurs with adding two elements into the aplusb integer and I've tried fixing it with writing

```
int aplusb = (lengthA[max-i]-'0') +(temp[max-i]-'0');
```

but it doesn't work. I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. Please help.

The whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    char a[10000];
    char b[10000];
    scanf("%s %s", &a, &b);
    char sum[10000];
    int lengthA = 0;
    int lengthB = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(a[i]){
        i++;
    } lengthA = i;

    i = 0;
    while(b[i]){
        i++;
    } lengthB = i;
    char temp[10000];

    int aplusb;
    int carry = 0;

    int max = lengthA;
    int difference = abs(lengthA - lengthB); 
    if(lengthA>lengthB){
        for(i=0; i<lengthA; i++){
            temp[i+difference]=b[i];
        }
        for(i=0; i<=max; i++){
            aplusb = lengthA[max-i]+temp[max-i]; //<-- this is the problematic line
            if(carry = 1) aplusb++;
            if(aplusb>9){
                carry = 1;
                aplusb%=10;
            }
            sum[i]=aplusb;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<=max; i++){
        printf("%c", sum[i]);
    }

    /*
    if(lengthB>lengthA){
        max = lengthB;
        for(i=0; i<lengthB; i++){
            temp[i+difference]=a[i];
        }
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `10 ^ 10000` is `10010`. An `int` is sufficient.

Comment: `if(carry = 1)` is assignment. Change to `if(carry == 1)`

Comment: i meant 10 to the power of 10000 @Olaf

Comment: Why so overly complicated? And why do you use a type with implementation defined signed-ness?

Comment: I couldn't come up with a simpler way of summing up giant numbers.
- also what did you mean with the second question, I'm not quite getting it. @Olaf

Comment: @Vid You don't even use `strlen()`, but instead roll your own. That's being overly complicated. And `char` is a small integer, but it's implementation-defined whether or not it's signed or unsigned. If you assume it to be one or the other, that's a mistake. After reading the `char`s from the user, it's a good idea to convert to some more well-specified type before doing arithmetic on the digits.

Comment: @unwind aah, alright. i'll create a new array of ints then, thank you for your advice. (regarding the strlen() function - i'm new to programming, and even though this is probably a basic function, i haven't used it before)

Answer (score 0):

Doing operations and storing on very large numbers is very akin to doing operations and storing polynomials, i.e. with x = 10. a0 + a1.10 + a2.10^2 ... + an.10^n.

There are many polynomial libraries on the Internet, where you could find inspiration.  All operations on your very large numbers can be expressed in terms of polynomials.  This means that by using base 2^8, or even base 2^63, instead of base 10 to internally store your large numbers you would greatly improve performance.

You must also normalize your coefficients after operations to keep them positive.  Operations may result in a negative coefficient, That can easily be fixed, as it is very similar to borrowing after a subtraction, this means coefficients must be larger than your base by 1bit.

To convert back to base 10, you'd need to solve r (your result) for v (your value), such as r(10)=v(2^63).  This has only one solution, if you enforce the positive coefficients rule.

[note] After thinking about it some more: the rule on positive coefficients may only be necessary for printing, after all.

Example: adding. **no memory error checking**

```
int addPolys(signed char** result, int na, const signed char* a, int nb, const signed char* b)
{
  int i, nr, nmin, carry, *r;

  nr = max(na, nb) + 1;
  nmin = min(na, nb);

  r = malloc(sizeof(signed char) * (na + nb + 1));

  if (nb < na)
  {
    nr = nb;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < nmin; ++i)
  {
    r[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
  for (; i < na; ++i)
  {
    r[i] = a[i];
  }
  for (; i < nb; ++i)
  {
    r[i] = b[i];
  }
  r[nr - 1] = 0;
  // carry - should really be a proc of its own, unoptimized
  carry = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < nr; ++i)
  {
    r[i] += carry;
    if (r[i] > 10)
    {
       carry = r[i] / 10;
       r[i] %= 10;
    }
    else if (r[i] < 0)
    {
       carry = (r[i] / 10) - 1;
       r[i] -= (carry * 10);
    }
    else
      carry = 0;
  }

  // 'remove' leading zeroes 
  for (i = nr - 1; i > 0; --i)
  {
    if (r[i] != 0) break;
  } 
  ++i;

  *result = r;
  if (i != nr)
  {      
    *result = realloc(i * sizeof(signed char));  
  }
  return i;  // return number of digits (0 being 1 digit long)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer, but I'll first try summing by implementing arrays of ints. I had the +1 bit in mind :).

Comment: Yes, it may be simpler to work with base 10.  The maths are the same.

Comment: I wrote a polynomials library quite a while back.  It's in c++, unfortunately, but it defines all basic functions, such as add, multiply and divide polynomials.  http://mroy.chez-alice.fr/polynomials/index.html

Answer (score 0):

That code is working now for any two positive numbers with up to ten thousand digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char chara[10000];
    char charb[10000];
    scanf("%s %s", &chara, &charb);
    int lengthA = strlen(chara);
    int lengthB = strlen(charb);
    int max = lengthA;
    if(lengthB>lengthA) max=lengthB;
    int dif = abs(lengthA - lengthB);

    //ustvari int tabele
    int a[max];
    int b[max];
    int sum[max+1];

    // nastavi nule
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        a[i] = 0;
        b[i] = 0;
        sum[i] = 0;
    } sum[max] = 0;

    //prekopiraj stevila iz char v int tabele &obrni vrstni red

    for(i=0; i<lengthA; i++){
        a[i] = chara[lengthA-i-1]-'0';
    }
    for(i=0; i<lengthB; i++){
        b[i] = charb[lengthB-i-1]-'0';
    }

    int vsota;
    int prenos = 0;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        vsota = a[i]+b[i] + prenos;
        if(vsota>=10) prenos = 1;
        else if (vsota<10) prenos = 0;
        sum[i]=vsota%10;
    }

    if(prenos==1){
        sum[max] = 1;
        for(i = max; i>=0; i--){
            printf("%d", sum[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for(i = max-1; i>=0; i--){
            printf("%d", sum[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Detail: "working now for any two positive numbers with up to ten thousand digits" --> off by one. `chara[10000];` is sufficient for storing a 9999 digit _string_.  Need 1 for the _null character_.

Comment: Simplification: Instead of `if(vsota>=10) prenos = 1;
        else if (vsota<10) prenos = 0;
        sum[i]=vsota%10;`, consider `sum[i]=vsota%10; prenos = vsota/10;`